# Convert MongoDB BasicDBList to Java short[] Array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I have inserted a 1D short[] array to MongoDB. It was easy.Now I am trying to retreive the same array. It returns a BasicDBList.I want to do some manipulation on the elements of the list. Hence, I want to convert it to
Java short[] back. How can I do this ?

Following is the code:

/* Insert the 1DArray*/

```
    DB dB = (new MongoClient("localhost",27017)).getDB("Test1DArray");
    DBCollection dbcollection = dB.getCollection("Test1DArray");
    BasicDBObject aisDocument = new BasicDBObject();
    aisDocument.append("TDArray",out1D);
    dbcollection.insert(aisDocument);
```

/* Fetch the 1DArray*/

```
    ObjectId MLMatrixObjectsID = (ObjectId)aisDocument.get( "_id" );
    System.out.println(MLMatrixObjectsID);
    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
    fields.put("_id", MLMatrixObjectsID);
    DBCollection dbcollectionfetch = dB.getCollection("Test1DArray");
    DBCursor cursor = dbcollectionfetch.find(fields);

    BasicDBList ODarr=null;
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        ODarr = (BasicDBList)(cursor.next().get("TDArray"));
        for(int cell=0; cell < ODarr.size(); cell++){
            System.out.println(ODarr.get(cell));
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Object[]  str  =  `ODarr.toArray();
short[] x  =  new short[str.length];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { 
x[i]=((Integer) str[i]).shortValue();
}

Does this help ?

Comment: @professionallyme86: why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @professionallyme86 . Wonderful. Your answer also worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[]  str  =  `ODarr.toArray();
short[] x  =  new short[str.length];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {  
x[i]=((Integer) str[i]).shortValue();}
```

Does this help ?

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you so much.